# Reload Fragment after DialogFragment dismisses

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have Index.class as the Activity, when the user choose Profile, it will call fragment Profile

```
  if (id == R.id.nav_profile){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter,R.anim.exit,R.anim.enter,R.anim.exit);
        transaction.replace(R.id.flContent, new Profile(), "ProfileFragment");
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Now in Profile Fragment, when the user clicks a button it will call DevRegistration Activity

```
 case 1:
            btnBeDeveloper.setText("Developer Console");
            btnBeDeveloper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     Intent index = new Intent(getActivity(), DevRegistration.class);
                    startActivity(index);
                }
            });
            break;
```

Then in DevRegistration class, after I click the register button, it will display a dialog fragment class.
What I want to do is when I click the button inside the dialog fragment, how can I refresh the profile fragment?

Dialog Fragment Class:

```
public class df_SuccessDevRegistration extends DialogFragment {

Button btnDevGoProfile;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_success_developer_registration, container, false);

    btnDevGoProfile = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnDevGoProfile);

    btnDevGoProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getActivity().finish();

            Profile fragment = (Profile)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ProfileFragment");

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            transaction.detach(fragment);
            transaction.attach(fragment);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

}

By the way, I dont know why getSupportFragmentManager isnt working. It shows an error cannot resolve method... when I used getFragmentManager() it crashes.

Comment: use custom listener interface

Comment: Can you share your dialog fragment class , please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try this to refresh the current fragment

```
 FragmentTransaction ftran = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ftran .detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Comment: I have my fragment inside a folder[ java->packageName->Fragments ] and can't use .detach(this). Please help

Answer (score 0):

In your dev registration activity , get your fragment :

```
Profile profileFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ProfileFragment");
```

To refresh it you can try :

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.detach(profileFragment);
transaction.attach(profileFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

EDIT:

Can you try this ?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_success_developer_registration, container, false);

    btnDevGoProfile = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnDevGoProfile);



    return rootView;
}

@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        btnDevGoProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();


            Profile fragment = (Profile)
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ProfileFragment");

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            transaction.detach(fragment);
            transaction.attach(fragment);
            transaction.commit();

            getActivity().finish();
            dismiss();

        }
    });
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should I place the code in DevRegistration Activity or in my Dialog Fragment? I need to refresh the code after I click the button inside the dialog fragment.

Comment: The dialog fragment is in your DevRegistration Activity, right ?

Comment: it is a dialogfragment class, another class.

Comment: In final Activity activity, i got error, incompatible types: 
required: Activity
found: v4.support.fragment

Comment: try final DevRegistration activity = (DevRegistration) getActivity();

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: capstoreit.capstoreit.DevRegistration.DevRegistration cannot be cast to capstoreit.capstoreit.Index.Index

Maybe because Profile Fragment is called inside Index Activity not in DevRegistration class

Comment: Ha ok , my mistake so try final Index activity = (Index) getActivity();

Comment: No, it's correct, the problem is on my code my process is Index -> Profile Fragment -> Dev Registration Class -> Success Dialog Fragment --> should return to Profile Fragment but it must be refreshed. i think the problem is the dialog fragment is in dev registration class.

Comment: getActivity() <-- the activity called is the devregistration not the index

Comment: Thx for precision, a make some change on the onClick() method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138334/discussion-between-paul-john-pulumbarit-and-cochi).